Azure ML Experiment Metric Limit: Unable to See All Logged Metrics in Experiment Comparison
I am conducting an experiment where I am logging metrics for 12 different machine learning models in Azure Machine Learning (Azure ML). Each model has 680 metrics. This is because I have a multiclassification model with more than 150 classes, and for each of them I have precision, recall, f1-score and support values.
Here's how I'm logging the metrics:
# Logging metrics using mlflow
mlflow.log_metric(f'{metric_name}', metric_value)

These metrics appear in the Run Details tab and I can view all of them when I look at individual runs. However, when I switch to the Experiment level to compare the models, I am only able to see a maximum of 250 metrics across all runs.
run metrics

experiment metrics

It seems like this might be a limitation in Azure ML, but I am unsure whether it's an issue with the service, my configuration, or if there's a known limitation in Azure ML or MLflow regarding the number of metrics that can be displayed at the experiment level.
Things I've tried:

Verified that all metrics are being logged correctly in the run details.
Ensured that the metrics are available in the mlflow.log_metric() call.
Checked Azure ML documentation and configuration settings, but couldn't find any references to a metric limit.

Question:

Is there a known limit to the number of metrics that can be displayed in the experiment comparison view in Azure ML?
Are there any configuration changes or workarounds to overcome this limitation?
Should I consider using a different logging method for a larger number of metrics?


go to job comparison by scroll down in experiment and check if all the metrics are compared or not.

@JayashankarGS if you mean the table comparison I have only 250 metrics as limit. And I am unable to select the other metrics that are present in the single jobs

no job comparison. it compares metrices separately. at last you can find in metrics comparison tab

@JayashankarGS in the process tab I don't have the comparison tab. It is present under the models sections (as preview), but my processes don't register a model, they are done as post process of the training

Under experiments click on dashboard view you will get

@JayashankarGS ah ok. I was already there. It's there that I see only 250 metrics for compaarison. But the single runs of the experiments have more thant 680 metrics
